# `shell: bash -l {0}` in GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, shell, github-actions

When I use [setup-miniconda](https://github.com/conda-incubator/setup-miniconda/blob/23dfbf7fc77cdca3333feeb1986f2e47b50ff610/README.md#use-a-default-shell), it uses `shell: bash -l {0}` in GitHub Actions:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    name: Foo
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
```

When I use [CML](https://github.com/iterative/cml_cloud_case/blob/0bd4dd7f08b2133a0ed978ceb8ff5155e095f3cc/.github/workflows/cml.yaml#L14). It only uses `shell: bash` without `-l {0}`.

I found some explanation at [GitHub Actions doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#custom-shell):

> You can set the `shell` value to a template string using `command […options] {0} [..more_options]`. GitHub interprets the first whitespace-delimited word of the string as the command, and inserts the file name for the temporary script at `{0}`.

However, I am still not clear what are the functions of `-l` and `{0}`? For `-l`, is it a parameter of `bash`?

Appreciate for some explanations!

Comment: `-l` means of course _run as login shell_ (see the bash man page), but I have no idea what the `{0}` is supposed to do. It does not make sense in the bash context at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be linked to [issue 128](https://github.com/conda-incubator/setup-miniconda/issues/128) which states:

> I got stuck for a while because my run commands were not using a login bash shell.
> So the conda environment was not active.
>
> Would be helpful to warn about that and recommend something like the following in the yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -l {0}
```

With:

- `-l` to insure a *login* bash, where the environment is correctly set;
- `{0}`, a template placeholder, replaced at pipeline execution time by the actual script command to execute.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, would like to get some explanations of `-l {0}` part as I found some codes online are using it, some are not.

Comment: @HongboMiao The `-l` is the important part, in order to insure a login bash, where the environment is correctly set.

Comment: Got it! I tried to run `bash -l` in my local terminal and it started a bash session. What about `{0}`?

Comment: `and inserts the file name for the temporary script at {0}`: that is a template placeholder, replaced at pipeline execution time by the actual script source file.